# myplainnat won't work anymore

Tags: bibtex, natbib, texshop

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
The top-level auxiliary file: Hausarbeit_die achtzigste.aux
The style file: myplainnat.bst
Ôªø is an illegal style-file command---line 1 of file myplainnat.bst
 : Ôªø
 :    %% File: `plainnat.bst'
key is an unknown function---line 247 of file myplainnat.bst
author is an unknown function---line 253 of file myplainnat.bst
```

I don't know what to do. Please help me.

Comment: This file worked fine for me for over a year, just now it stopped working entirely.. I am desperate

Comment: You say the .bst file did its job until very recently. Do you know what changed? E.g., do you have new bibliographic entries in a .bib file? If so, will the .bst file work again if you go back to the older version of the .bib file? Did you try blowing away all auxiliary files (esp those with extension .aux and .bbl) and recompiling from scratch? Did the file myplainnat.bst file itself get edited? If so, do you have a backup of the .bst file?